# Get only content of file and run `tpl` on this content [kubernetes-helm]

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I am not able to figure out a way to get the content of file and run `tpl` on this content

Yaml input input file :

```
spec:
{{- (tpl ($.Files.Glob config.yaml).AsConfig $) | nindent 2 }}
```

Content of config.yaml

```
key1: {{ .Values.value1 }}
key2: {{ .Values.value2 }}
```

Content of values.yaml file

```
value1: value1
value2: value2
```

Helm template output:

```
spec:
  config.yaml: |-
    key1: value2
    key2: value2
```

What I want

```
spec:
  # config.yaml: |- should be removed
  key1: value2
  key2: value2
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `.Files.Get` instead of `Glob` method.

```yaml
spec:
{{ tpl ( .Files.Get "config.yaml" ) . | indent 2 }}
```

For more details, visit - [Accessing Files Inside Templates](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/)